# classic asp - reading csv file having alphanumeric data

Tags: csv, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm having trouble in reading csv file that are having alphanumeric data. below is my code  in classic asp:

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
ls_map_path & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"


Set lo_conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
lo_conn.Open strConn

Set lo_rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
lo_rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
lo_rs.open "SELECT * FROM " & as_file_name, lo_conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

and below is the data:

```
user_id,status,last_name,first_name,middle_name 
1234,1,DeVera,athan,M. 
1234,1,De Vera,athan,M. 
ABC1,1,Santos,Shaine
abcd,1,Santos,Luis 
1234,1,De Vera,athan,M. 
1234,1,De Vera,athan,M.
ABC1,1,Santos,Shaine
```

When reading "user_id" column using `lo_rs.fields.Item("user_id")`, it perfectly retrieve the "1234" user_id value. but other data that are having alphanumeric value is returning me a null.

I don't know the reason why it is returning null. Though, if the data is all alphanumeric then it perfectly reads the user_id column. I think the only problem is, if the csv data is having a mix numeric and alphanumeric value in one column.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? or maybe I just have a missing text in the connection string.

Please advise and thank you very much for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around the type inference you can create a [`SCHEMA.INI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx) that defines the types of each column in the CSV file.

Set `HDR=NO` & in the directory containing the CSV (`ls_map_path`) create a schema.ini:

```
[filenamehere.csv]
Col1=user_id Text
Col2=status Long
Col3=last_name Text
Col4=middle_name Text
```

The type mappings used by the text provider are now based on the above schema.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Though the csv file is uploaded and being read by my web site. Meaning, Each time a user upload a csv file I should re-create the schema.ini file? Thanks.

Comment: You can change it globally by making `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text\ImportMixedTypes=Text` instead of `Majority Type`

Comment: 6 years on this just helped me, thank you. I hope you are still so helpful by explaining the change to make this global, is the snippet you included above a command I need to type or something?

Comment: The registry change should be global as far as I can remember.